# WebView Display White or Blank page

Tags: android, android-webview

does anyone know why webview displaying white page?
Here is the code

```
webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(THE_URL);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

and this functions is also called:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
}
```

am I missing something there?
Of course, the error is not from the XML, because the webview only does not display some URL.

Thanks

Comment: Did you give this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest?

Comment: of course..it displays the other html

Comment: Don't remember. But you should try adding "http://" in front of it. It may make it works.

Comment: Check `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method's url value using debugging. Sometimes it comes as "about:blank" and it loads a blank page.

Comment: Did u find any solution? I have also the same problem?

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still having this issue, it seems that the WebViewClient does not warn you if a secure connection via https has failed. This is likely due to an SSL error on the server you are connecting to.

You can try using http instead if the server allows it.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [link](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-webview-to-load-url.html). In your code you are creating two webview clients simultaneously.

```
mwebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mwebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mwebview.loadUrl(webUrl);
mwebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your activity try this,

**main.xml**

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

   <Textview android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="This is the demo of WebView Client" android:textsize="20sp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
   </Textview>

   <Webview android:id="@+id/webview01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
   </Webview>

   <Imageview android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">      

</Imageview></Linearlayout>
```

**WebViewClientDemoActivity.java**

```
   import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    /*
     * Demo of creating an application to open any URL inside the application and clicking on any link from that URl
    should not open Native browser but  that URL should open in the same screen.
     */
    public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        WebView web;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
            web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }

        public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }
        }

        // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
       @Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
      {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }
    }
```

In your **manifest.xml** use these permisions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Just now i edited my post try this code for your url. In manifest i added other two permissions (Coarse_Location and Fine_Location are used only for when you find use location based application any way try this and give me the feed back).

Comment: @Rendy: May i know your URL value?

Comment: i have used it in my application since before i have this webview. What do you mean by URL value? the parameter inside it?

Comment: what is the link you are try to load, for example here i load www.google.com

Comment: sorry can't give it to you because it's confidential :)

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your container view background and then set

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```